# nodejs sql azure best way to connect

Tags: node.js, azure-sql-database

I am trying to connect to a Azure SQL Server database from my nodejs app.  I tried using "msnodesql" but this fails on install itself, and the components it depends on are so old that I have serious doubts on downgrading my installations just to support this.  So my question is, what is the best way (modules) to use in order to connect to SQL Azure?  I found the following https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql, are there any known drawbacks in using this?

Answer (score 0):

@spdev There are no drawbacks in using mssql. It uses Tedious under the hood. Here is some getting started documentation for Tedious with Azure SQL DB on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install node
sudo apt-get install npm

sudo npm init
sudo npm install tedious
```

Here is some sample code

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var config = {
    userName: 'yourusername',
    password: 'yourpassword',
    server: 'yourserver.database.windows.net',
    // When you connect to Azure SQL Database, you need these next options.
    options: {encrypt: true, database: 'AdventureWorks'}
};
var connection = new Connection(config);
connection.on('connect', function(err) {
    // If no error, then good to proceed.
    console.log("Connected");
    executeStatement();

});

var Request = require('tedious').Request;
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;

function executeStatement() {
    request = new Request("SELECT TOP 10 Title, FirstName, LastName from SalesLT.Customer;", function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);} 
    });
    var result = "";
    request.on('row', function(columns) {
        columns.forEach(function(column) {
          if (column.value === null) {
            console.log('NULL');
          } else {
            result+= column.value + " ";
          }
        });
        console.log(result);
        result ="";
    });

    request.on('done', function(rowCount, more) {
    console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');
    });
    connection.execSql(request);
}
```